# Creating dynamic RadiobuttonList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What im trying to accomplish is I have a table which im creating dynamically and I want in the first tablecell a radiobutton, second tablecell first name, third tablecell last name. The second and third tablecell work fine but having trouble with the radiobutton. Im making it a radiobutton list b/c only one name should be selectable. Below is how im creating the radiobutton list. I have omitted the second and third tablecell as its working properly. The yesNo variable is used to say is this the first row in the table. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
 tblrow = New TableHeaderRow
 tblcell = New TableCell

   If yesNo = "yes" Then
    radList = New RadioButtonList
    radList.ID = newVar & "_list"   
   Else
    Dim item As New ListItem
     radList.Items.Add(item)    
   End If

   tableName.Rows.Add(tblrow)
```

Comment: Why don't you show the complete loop? What is the datasource of your table? Are the names static or from database?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating a new RadioButtonList with one button in it for every row.

Try using instead the HtmlInputRadioButton class. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputradiobutton%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a nice description of it and it's use.

Here's the relevant bit:

> HtmlInputRadioButton controls can be grouped together by specifying a common value for the Name property of each radio button you want to include in the group.
>
> **Note**   When you group HtmlInputRadioButton controls together, only one radio button in the group can be selected at a time.